# Why can't my function take the user input?

Tags: c, io, scanf

```
void patient_data(){    

    char name[10];
    int ID[4];
    int age;
    char history[100];
    float temp;
    int breath; 

    printf("enter patient data:\n");    

    scanf("name : %s\n", name);
    scanf("ID: %d\n",ID);
    scanf("age %d\n",&age);
    scanf("history: %s\n", history);
    scanf("temp: %f\n",&temp);
    scanf("breath: %s\n", breath);

    FILE *info;
    info = fopen("info.txt","a");   

    fscanf(info,"%s     %d  %d  %s  %f  %d",name, ID, &age, history, &temp,&breath);
}
```

this code is supposed to take user input for patient data and save it in a file that should be accessed later, but the scanf functions are not working.

any Idea on what might be the issue here?

Comment: *...are not working* Please elaborate.

Comment: This reads the data from the file, not from user input. If you wanted to take user input and then save it to a file, you would `scanf` it from the user and then `fprintf` it to the file.

Comment: You open `info` for writing and then use a read function (fscanf)

Answer (score 3):

Your `scanf'`s are ill-formed, they should simply be:

```
scanf(" %9s", name); //<-- added buffer limit
scanf("%d",ID);
scanf("%d",&age);
scanf(" %99s", history); //<-- added buffer limit
scanf("%f",&temp);
scanf("%d", &breath);` // <-- corrected the specifier
```

If you want to print tags for the user to know what to input use `printf` or `puts` before every `scanf`.

Note that the last `scanf` has a specifier missmatch, it takes an integer but uses a string specifier.

Also note that the `"%s"` specifier is unsafe, you should use `"%99s"` for a 100 char container to avoid buffer overflow. The way you have it, [it's no better than `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6865932).

Finally the correct function to write to a file is [`fprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

```
fprintf(info,"%s     %d  %d  %s  %f  %d", name, ID, age, history, temp, breath);
```